# Give regular expressions of Σ = {a, b}

Tags: math

The question ask me to give regular expressions on Σ = {a, b}, which exactly define the following languages.

These are;

(a) L1 which has exactly one b but any number of as.

(b) L2 which has an even number of as and an even number of bs.

I am struggling on what would the answers be. I would appreciate if you could help me out. Thank you

Comment: Show your attempts so far. "I am struggling" is not good enough.

Answer (score 2):

(a) We need exactly one b, which can occur anywhere in our strings; and we can have any number of the other symbols, the only one of which is a; so, our regular expression is (a*)b(a*) (note: the parentheses are added for clarity only and can be omitted).

(b) A little more complicated. See below.

(c) We can write regular expressions for each case and then union them to get one regular expression; the cases are just like (a) above: (a*)b(a*)b(a*) + (b*)a(b*)a(b*)

(d) Again, we can do each case separately and union the answers: (a*)(b*) + (b*)(a*)

(e) A little more complicated, though easier than (b). See below.

For (b) and (e) I recommend writing down a finite automaton, then a regular grammar, then solving the set of implied equations to find the regular expression. I will do (e) as an example and leave (b) as an exercise.

A finite automaton for (e) is this:

```
  +---a-----+
  |         |
  V         |
(q0)--a-->(q1)
|  ^      |  ^
+-b|      +-b|
```

The regular grammar is this:

```
(q0) -> e | a(q1) | b(q0)
(q1) -> a(q0) | b(q1)
```

The set of implied equations:

```
(q0) = e + a(q1) + b(q0)
(q1) = a(q0) + b(q1)
```

We can simplify each line using the rule `q = rq + s => q = r*s`:

```
(q0) = (b*)[a(q1) + e] = (b*)a(q1) + (b*)
(q1) = (b*)a(q0)
```

Now we substitute and simplify:

```
(q0) = (b*)a(b*)a(q0) + (b*)
     = [(b*)a(b*)a]*(b*)
```

There you have your answer: a regular expression for (e) is `[(b*)a(b*)a]*(b*)`. Now that we have the answer to look at it sort of makes sense: the part in square brackets contains exactly two a's, starring it gives any even number, and then finishing with b* means we don't need an a on the end (though we can have one if we want to).

For (b): either do what we did for (e) (note that you will have a four-state DFA, four nonterminals and four equations, but you can solve the system the same way we just did), or use the other expressions we've made and any insights you've gleaned to see if there's a simpler way to combine things to get the required expression.